# Problems with animate defining number of pixels

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

This code produces no result. I need the variable, as the number is different each time the user clicks. Is it not possible to define the number of pixels this way? Thanks for any help.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#logo").click(function () {
        var num = (whatever);
        $("#slideshow").animate({left: "-=num + 'px'"}, 2000);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably getting an error for passing a string that is not a valid unit value, you need to concatenate the value of your variable like this

```
$("#slideshow").animate({left: '-=' + num}, 2000);
```

Also you don't need to specify pixels, any number without unit is treated like pixels